# TCP Server Timeout while peeking stream reader error

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, tcplistener

I have a TCP server which has a receive timeout of 9 seconds, however, I am using to receive any data from the client:

```
while (sr.Peek() >= 0) {
    line += sr.ReadLine();
    line += Environment.NewLine;
}
```

But when the server times out I get the following error on the sr.Peek() line:

> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

Is there a way of having a timeout but also waiting for any potential data from the client?

Comment: There's not enough context to provide any sort of real answer. But, short version: don't use a socket timeout. When it expires, it renders the socket unusable. Unless your goal is to drop the connection after the timeout period, that's the wrong thing to do. It's also the wrong thing to do to use `Peek()`. Just use `await sr.ReadLineAsync()`. Finally, avoid using string concatenation in a loop. Use a `StringBuilder` instead.

Comment: I want to drop the connection after the timeout. Thanks for the other advice. How would I know if there's any further data if I don't use Peek? What other contextual information would you like?

Comment: The main issue is the fact the stream reader causes the error as it's attempting to read it and it doesn't like it when it's timed out? I don't understand.

Comment: _"it doesn't like it when it's timed out?"_ -- why should it "like it"? The connection has been dropped. There's never going to be anything to read at that point. It makes sense to me that the attempt to perform an I/O operation (i.e. the "peek") will throw an exception when used with an object that is no longer valid.